# LaTeX Error: Command \anw@print already defined on build

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I am working on a large tex document that was running pretty smoothly, until now that I upgraded to Linux mint 20.3 and reinstall texlive-full. I was using xelatex as my compiler, but now every time I try to build and view my project's PDF I get the following three error messages (**related to the gloss-greek.ldf file**) and the build continues until producing the pdf file. From what I've seen so far searching, it might have to do something about the polyglossia package but I am not sure, and I don't know how to fix that as well.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \anw@print already defined.Or name \end... illegal
l.248 \newrobustcmd\anw@print{}

! LaTeX Error: Command \anw@false already defined.Or name \end... illegal                                                  
l.250   \renewrobustcmd\anw@print{}}

! LaTeX Error: Command \anw@true already defined.Or name \end... illegal
l.252    \renewrobustcmd\anw@print{ʹ}}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please, add a minimal example. [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Hello and thank you. You are correct, but there is no specific error in my document so I don't know what part of the whole document might be of use. It's a whole book, that was running smoothly so far...

Comment: you have an error. Start with the first one and try to find out why \anw@print is already defined. As this is probably already in the preamble it should be easy to make a minimal example.

Comment: you show a specifc error `! LaTeX Error: Command \anw@print already defined.Or name \end... illegal` on line 248 of some file (but you do not show which file) presumably though a package file so you should be to make a small example with just package loading and empty`document`

Comment: As the OP mentioned, those seem to come from the polyglossia greek package https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/gloss-greek.ldf

Comment: It seems that there is a possibility that polyglossia ldf files somehow got loaded multiple times. [One of the recent commits aimed at solving this for some LDFs](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/commit/f56b8162aae85ff623ebfe4f7aa31c9f94e96a4a), which included the **gloss-greek.ldf** file but _only_ those commands defined via `\newcommand` and not those defined via `\newrobustcommand`. I suggest filing a issue on GitHub referencing that earlier commit and pointing out that the same problem would happen also to any calls to `\newrobustcommand`.